# sqoop from mysql with split-limit parameter is giving error

Tags: mysql, sqoop

[image]I am trying to sqoop form MySQL, when i pass --split-limit parameter its not working.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://host:port/db_name --username user \
--password pass --query 'select p.* from table1 p join table2 m on \
p.id=m.id WHERE $CONDITIONS' --split-by 'p.id' --target-dir /path \
--direct --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --boundary-query 'select min(id), \
max(id) from tbl_kmart_sales_predicted_weekly_class where (1 = 0)' \
--delete-target-dir --split-limit 10
```

Error is :

```
16/12/03 05:57:48 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
16/12/03 05:57:48 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --split-limit
16/12/03 05:57:48 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 10
```

But same query works fine when i remove split-limit

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://host:port/db_name --username user \
--password pass --query 'select p.* from table1 p join table2 m on \
p.id=m.id WHERE $CONDITIONS' --split-by 'p.id' --target-dir /path \
--direct --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --boundary-query 'select min(id), \
max(id) from tbl_kmart_sales_predicted_weekly_class where (1 = 0)' \
--delete-target-dir
```

Answer (score 1):

I think split-limit was introduced in version 1.4.7

I don't see any mention of it in the docs prior to this version

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

**There is nothing like `--split-limit` in sqoop.**

I guess you are trying to give parameter to run sqoop jobs in *parallel*.

Use `-m 10` or `--num-mappers 10` instead of `--split-limit 10`.

Check [Controlling Parallelism](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism) for more details.

Comment: We have a --split-limit parameter. For more details please find attached screenshot.

Comment: @ShwethaJog which version of sqoop are you referring to? Please share link of the docs.

Comment: version is : 4.6 https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_literal